# How do I tell a `dotnet ef migrations` command point to a specific appsettings.json file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

So I have a project with multiple appsetting files depending on my environment, which works fine when running it, but when I try to add a migration, it's not going to the right `appsettings` file and is throwing an error.

So let's say I have `appsettings.Production.json`:

```
{
  "UseInMemoryDatabase": false,
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "HelloDb": "Data Source=localhost\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=HelloDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

and I have `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
{
  "UseInMemoryDatabase": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Now, I can run these just fine from VS using their respective profiles, but when I try and do an ef migration like so:

```sh
dotnet ef migrations add "InitialMigration" --project Infrastructure.Persistence --startup-project WebApi --output-dir Migrations
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
```

I know it's doing this because it's going to my plain old `appsettings.json` file (which is empty), but I don't know how to tell it to point to the proper file. It looks like there is a `--configuration` option that I can use, but that's just pointing to debug/release.

The docs say something about `To specify the environment for ASP.NET Core projects, set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable before running commands.`, but says nothing about how to do that. I've tried changing my profile (which in turn adjusts my `Environment Variables` selection), but that doesn't work.

I've also tried `set` commands like `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#evcp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging into this more and talking to the EF team, it looks like this isn't possible as a one liner yet, but is on their radar. For now, you have to set the environment variable. How you do that depends on your operating system and shell. Here's some search results for [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10), [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables), and [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7).

[This](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8695) is the github issue they are using to track this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Look at in your launchSetting.json

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
...
```

This is the place where ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set.

**dotnet ef** also rebuild your Visual Studio project, but this build in some cases is not the same as the Visual Studio build. So to avoid issues, build first your project with right configuration, then run dotnet ef with option **--no-build** and **--verbose** for detailed log.

Comment: Sure, that’s the profile and the env variable, but what parameter can I use in my dotnet ef command to tell it which profile to run?

Comment: @PaulDeVito if you build first with Visual Studio and use --no-build with dotnet ef, you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: Will give it a try, but even if that’s the case that’s not really ideal if I have to open up visual studio and do that completely separate from the command line operation. Major gap if that’s the only way to do it